# How can I add a blank page before the title of a book in tex or lyx?

Tags: lyx, books

I was trying to make a little booklet in Lyx.
I want to export it to .pdf and then use to brochure-print function of adobe reader.
Anyway I need to put an extra blank page in before the title page so that the book starts with a "left" (even) page which is blank and can later be glued into the binding.
I hope you dont punish me for using Lyx...
Thanks for the help!

Comment: i actually just found a solution. it is by putting this in front of the author:                                                         \mbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

Comment: Self-answers are perfectly admissible here, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation. So, go ahead, and type up a solution so that future LyX users can also benefit from this.

Comment: @Werner And not only LyX users, this is a common way I insert the empty page in a coded LaTeX too (I just possibly add `\thispagestyle{empty}` when necessary)

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in comments, one way to solve this is to add

```
\mbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
```

in an ERT at the very beginning of the document.